How to programmatically change the duration of TouchEffects.LongPress in Xamarin Forms
How do I change the duration of the long press on run time?
I have one image(button) where it has 2 different long press mode - 2 seconds and 5 seconds.
Both are separated by different modes so there wont be any conflicts when duration goes to 2 seconds to 5 seconds.
If Mode is A - duration should be 2 seconds, if Mode is B - duration should be 5 seconds.
I'm currently coding in Xamarin.Forms.
